# PyPDF2 merging issue with large files / Merge large PDFs with Python

Tags: python, pdf, merge, large-files, pypdf

i try to merge to pdf files in python with PyPDF2. 
The problem is the file size. 
So is there any other way to merge the files without file-size limit and memory problems ?

File-size 1 = 900MB 
File-size 2 = 300MB

For my understanding.  Is there a way to load only the last page of the first pdf and attach the second pdf ?

My Code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

merger = PdfFileMerger()

filename1 = 'document-output3.pdf'
filename2 = 'file1.pdf'

merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename1, 'rb')))
merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename2, 'rb')))

merger.write("document-output3.pdf")
```

-- Error Message --

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\eclipse-workspace\PyPDF2\MergePDF\mergepdf.py", line 13, in <module>
    merger.write("document-output5.pdf")   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 230, in write
    self.output.write(fileobj)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 482, in write
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 556, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 586, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    newobj = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, newobj)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 577, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    newobj = data.pdf.getObject(data)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1611, in getObject
    retval = readObject(self.stream, self)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 66, in readObject
    return DictionaryObject.readFromStream(stream, pdf)   File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 611, in readFromStream
    data["__streamdata__"] = stream.read(length) MemoryError
```

Thanks for your attention, 
Fabian